AVMutableVideoComposition: Overlay Static Text
In Swift for iOS, I have an array of AVURLAsset. I pass it through a function to stitch/merge the video assets together into one final video. For each video, my goal is to overlay text centered in the video frame.
When I play the video output, the video assets merge correctly, but no text overlays for any of the video assets. I tried following an existing answer, but no success. I also tried just overlaying text to a single video following Ray Wenderlich's tutorial, but for some reason the same end result :(.
Any guidance would be extremely appreciated..
func merge(videos: [AVURLAsset], completion: @escaping (_ url: URL, _ asset: AVAssetExportSession)->()) {
let videoComposition = AVMutableComposition()
var lastTime: CMTime = .zero

var maxVideoSize = CGSize.zero

guard let videoCompositionTrack = videoComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)),
      let audioCompositionTrack = videoComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else { return }

let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()

let mainParentLayer = CALayer()
let mainVideoLayer = CALayer()
mainParentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maxVideoSize.width, height: maxVideoSize.height)
mainVideoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maxVideoSize.width, height: maxVideoSize.height)

mainParentLayer.addSublayer(mainVideoLayer)

var instructions = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction]()
    
print("Main Parent Layer Frame: \(mainParentLayer.frame)")

for video in videos {
    
    if let videoTrack = video.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[safe: 0] {
        videoCompositionTrack.preferredTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
        print("Video Track Transform: \(videoTrack.preferredTransform)")

        do {
            try videoCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: video.duration), of: videoTrack, at: lastTime)
            print("Video time range: Start = \(lastTime.seconds), Duration = \(video.duration.seconds) [\(lastTime.seconds + video.duration.seconds > 0 ? "Right" : "Wrong")]")

            if let audioTrack = video.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[safe: 0] {
                try audioCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: video.duration), of: audioTrack, at: lastTime)
            }

            lastTime = CMTimeAdd(lastTime, video.duration)

            let videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize.applying(videoTrack.preferredTransform)
            let videoRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: abs(videoSize.width), height: abs(videoSize.height))
            maxVideoSize = CGSize(width: max(maxVideoSize.width, videoRect.width), height: max(maxVideoSize.height, videoRect.height))

            let textLayer = CATextLayer()
            textLayer.string = "TESTING TESTING TESTING"
            textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            textLayer.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: min(videoRect.height / 10, 100))
            textLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
            textLayer.alignmentMode = .center
            textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
            textLayer.isWrapped = true

            let textHeight: CGFloat = min(videoRect.height / 10, 120)
            let textWidth: CGFloat = videoRect.width
            let xPos = (videoRect.width - textWidth) / 2
            let yPos = (videoRect.height - textHeight) / 2
            textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: textWidth, height: textHeight)
            textLayer.zPosition = 1
            print("Text Layer Frame: \(textLayer.frame) [\(textLayer.frame.width > 0 && textLayer.frame.height > 0 ? "Right" : "Wrong")]")

            let parentLayer = CALayer()
            parentLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor // Temp background color for debugging
            parentLayer.frame = videoRect
            parentLayer.addSublayer(textLayer)
            
            print("Video Layer zPosition: \(mainVideoLayer.zPosition), Text Layer zPosition: \(textLayer.zPosition) [\(textLayer.zPosition > mainVideoLayer.zPosition ? "Right" : "Wrong")]")

            let videoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: lastTime - video.duration, duration: video.duration)
            let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
            videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
            instructions.append(videoCompositionInstruction)

            parentLayer.zPosition = 0
            mainParentLayer.addSublayer(parentLayer)
            
            print("Parent Layer Frame: \(parentLayer.frame), Background Color: \(parentLayer.backgroundColor.debugDescription)")
            print("Text Layer Frame: \(textLayer.frame)")
            
        } catch {
            print("Failed to insert track: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }
}

mainParentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maxVideoSize.width, height: maxVideoSize.height)
mainVideoLayer.frame = mainParentLayer.frame

mainComposition.renderSize = maxVideoSize
mainComposition.instructions = instructions
mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)
mainComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: mainVideoLayer, in: mainParentLayer)

print("Final Main Parent Layer Frame: \(mainParentLayer.frame)")
print("Number of Sublayers in Main Parent Layer: \(mainParentLayer.sublayers?.count ?? 0)")

let outputUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "merged" + ".mp4")

print("Pre-Export Main Parent Layer Frame: \(mainParentLayer.frame)")
print("Pre-Export Number of Sublayers in Main Parent Layer: \(mainParentLayer.sublayers?.count ?? 0)")
if let sublayers = mainParentLayer.sublayers {
    for (index, layer) in sublayers.enumerated() {
        print("Layer \(index): \(layer), Frame: \(layer.frame), zPosition: \(layer.zPosition)")
    }
}

guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }

exporter.videoComposition = mainComposition
exporter.outputURL = outputUrl
exporter.outputFileType = .mp4
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

if let videoComposition = exporter.videoComposition {
    print("Export Video Composition Render Size: \(videoComposition.renderSize)")
    print("Export Video Composition Frame Duration: \(videoComposition.frameDuration)")
    print("Export Video Composition Instructions Count: \(videoComposition.instructions.count)")
}

exporter.exportAsynchronously {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let outputUrl = exporter.outputURL, exporter.status == .completed {
            completion(outputUrl, exporter)
        } else if let error = exporter.error {
            print("Export failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
play(video: exporter.asset)
}


I run your code and it seems to be exporting the text as well, however there is one thing that I noticed. I believe you want to play the exported video not the constructed asset with no text attached to it. If the last line is correct and you play with the asset of exporter that is the issue. Try to create a new asset with the exported path and play that one instead once the export is finished (from your completion block). Replace
play(video: exporter.asset)
// with
play(video: AVAsset(url: outputUrl)

In addition, if you want to play the video without exporting there is an api for that as well. Try to use AVSynchronizedLayer.
Hope this helps.

So I do technically see the text overlay now when the video is played, but I only see it if I have play(video: AVAsset(url: outputUrl) in the completion handler of the exporter and the exporter.status == .completed. The benefit of how I had it originally was the video immediately played even if the exporter hadn't fully completed/loaded. Any solution on how to both keep the text overlay and the immediate playback?

There is an api to do that, but you'll need to create AVSynchronizedLayer instead. Here are some examples https://medium.com/@peteliev/avfoundation-understanding-avsynchronizedlayer-e922d2676b9
Basically you just need to create it with your playerItem with merged assets and add the text layers to that synchronized layer. For export you'll have to use the animation tool as you are doing in your code.
